# In React.js, TMDB API returns the same data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, clone, netflix

I'm trying to create a Netflix clone. I'm trying to show movies through an API called TMDB. But, when I try to view the movies, the content appears to be identical(in Action movies, Comedy movies, Romance movies and Documentaries) and the movie posters are not appearing in the Netflix originals area.

**CODE**

**App.js**

```js
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Row from './Row';
import requests from './requests';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
     <h1>HEY boiii!!</h1>
     <Row title="NETFLIX ORIGINALS" fetchUrl={requests.fetchNetflixOriginals} isLargeRow />
     <Row title="Trending Now" fetchUrl={requests.fetchTrending} />     
     <Row title="Top Rated" fetchUrl={requests.fetchTopRated} />  
     <Row title="Action Movies" fetchUrl={requests.fetchActionMovies} />  
     <Row title="Comedy Movies" fetchUrl={requests.fetchComedyMovies} />  
     <Row title="Horror Movies" fetchUrl={requests.fetchHorrorMovies} />  
     <Row title="Romance Movies" fetchUrl={requests.fetchRomanceMovies} />  
     <Row title="Documentaries" fetchUrl={requests.fetchDocumentaries} />  
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**request.js**

```js
const API_KEY = "API KEY";

const requests = {
    fetchTrending: `/trending/all/week?api_key=${API_KEY}&language=en-US`,
    fetchNetflixOriginals: `/discover/tv?api_key=${API_KEY}$with_networks=213`,
    fetchTopRated: `/movie/top_rated?api_key=${API_KEY}&language=en-US`,
    fetchActionMovies: `/discover/movie?api_key=${API_KEY}&with_genre=28`,
    fetchComedyMovies: `/discover/movie?api_key=${API_KEY}&with_genre=35`,
    fetchHorrorMovies: `/discover/movie?api_key=${API_KEY}&with_genre=27`,
    fetchRomanceMovies: `/discover/movie?api_key=${API_KEY}&with_genre=10749`,
    fetchDocumentaries: `/discover/movie?api_key=${API_KEY}&with_genre=99`,
  }
  export default requests;
```

**Row.js**

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from './axios';
import './Row.css';

const base_url ="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/";

function Row({ title, fetchUrl, isLargeRow }) {
useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
    const request = await axios.get(fetchUrl);
    setMovies(request.data.results);
    return request;
    }
    fetchData();
}, [fetchUrl]);

console.table(movies);

    return (
        <div className="row">
            <h2>{title}</h2>

            <div className="row__posters">
                {/* several row__poster(s) */}

                {movies.map(movie => (

                    
                <img key={movie.id} className ={`row__poster ${isLargeRow && "row__poster"}`} src={`${base_url}${ isLargeRow ? movie.poster_path : movie.backdrop_path}`} alt={movie.name}/>
                ))}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Row;
```

**Row.css**

```css
.row__posters {
  display: flex;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  padding: 20px;
}

.row__posters::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}
  

.row__poster {
 
  object-fit: contain;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 100px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  transition: transform 450ms;
}

.row__poster:hover {
  transform: scale(1.08);
}

.row__posterLarge {
  max-height: 250px;
}

.row__posterLarge:hover {
  transform: scale(1.09);
  opacity: 1;
}
```

**App.css**

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}
```

**axios.js**

```js
import axios from "axios";

const instance = axios.create({baseURL: "https://api.themoviedb.org/3"}); 

export default instance;
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently working on this project and ran into the same issue. I was able to get it working when I changed "genre" to "genres" in my request.js file. Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

The problem – most likely – is with `Row` component. Essentially `setMovies(...);` and `movies` seem to operate with an array that is outside of your component – e.g. global.

You'd want to change your function to use `useState(...)` hook. This way movies data would be 'attached' to your component and not a global context.

You can read hooks [documentation here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html)

```js
import './Row.css';
import React from 'react';

const base_url ="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/";

function Row({ title, fetchUrl, isLargeRow }) {
  const [movies, setMovies] = React.useState([]); // <-- HERE 

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      // TODO: make sure to do some validation here, what if request fails?
      const request = await axios.get(fetchUrl);
      setMovies(request.data.results);
      return request;
    }

    fetchData();
  }, [fetchUrl]);


    return (
        <div className="row">
            <h2>{title}</h2>

            <div className="row__posters">
                {/* several row__poster(s) */}

                {movies.map(movie => (

                    
                <img key={movie.id} className ={`row__poster ${isLargeRow && "row__poster"}`} src={`${base_url}${ isLargeRow ? movie.poster_path : movie.backdrop_path}`} alt={movie.name}/>
                ))}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Row;
```

Comment: Still my code is not working.

Answer (score 0):

```
import './Row.css';
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';


const base_url ="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/";

function Row({ title, fetchUrl, isLargeRow }) {
  const [movies, setMovies] = useState([]); // <-- HERE 

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      // TODO: make sure to do some validation here, what if request fails?
      const request = await axios.get(fetchUrl);
      setMovies(request.data.results);
      return request;
    }

    fetchData();
  }, [fetchUrl]);


    return (
        <div className="row">
            <h2>{title}</h2>

            <div className="row__posters">
                {/* several row__poster(s) */}

                {movies.map(movie => (

                    
                <img key={movie.id} className ={`row__poster ${isLargeRow && "row__poster"}`} src={`${base_url}${ isLargeRow ? movie.poster_path : movie.backdrop_path}`} alt={movie.name}/>
                ))}
            </div>`enter code here`
        </div>
    );
}

export default Row;
```

Comment: could you add some comments/text to your answer explaining what you've changed, and how this should make it work better?

Comment: its basically issue of http client, try refreshing base url, if you go to console of browser you will find the error (and thank you for commenting i couldnt comment this before.